# Why can't I see a red div box?

Tags: html, css, element, background-color

```css
body {
  background-color: teal;
}

.gridBox {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridBox">
  <div id="grid"> </div>
</div>
```

What's wrong with my .gridBox div? When I set it to pixels, I can see it. But percent doesn't work. Because it's a child element of body, doesn't .gridBox inherit the width and height of the browser window? Huh?

Comment: No, it takes its height from the body height, not the browser window.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `vh` and `vw` for the div instead of `%`. `20vh` is 20% of the viewport height, rather than the elements parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `width` and `height` of your div's parents. That's because this element takes `height` and `width` from the body, then html - which were not set.

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: teal;
}

.gridBox {
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridBox">
  <div id="grid"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you *explain* your modifications and **why** did you make them ?

Comment: Why not just use vh and vw ? Why use %? Is there any difference?

Comment: `vh` and `vw` are percentege of the viewport while "normal" % is percentage of the parent element

Comment: @Catlard Arkej's solution is compatible with more browsers, including old ones that didn't have `vh` and `vw` yet.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `vh` and `vw` instead of `%`.

`vh` is percentage of the viewport height.
`vw` is percentage of the viewport width.

```css
body {
  background-color: teal;
}

.gridBox {
  display: block;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 20vw;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridBox">
  <div id="grid"> </div>
</div>
```

On the other hand you could use `%`, but if you do you need to set `html` and `body` to `height: 100%; width: 100%;` and then `margin: 0;` to remove the extra space which causes scrollbars.

```css
body, html {
  background-color: teal;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.gridBox {
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridBox">
  <div id="grid"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use %? In what situation to you use % as opposed to vh and vw?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. The issue here is that you haven't set a width and height of `body/html`, so therefore when give `width: 20%; width: 20%;` it does not show. (20% of what?)

**Adding width & height of body/html**

```css
body,html {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.gridBox {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridBox">
  <div id="grid"> </div>
</div>
```

**This is with content**

If you add content it will show.

```css
 body {
      background-color: teal;
    }

    .gridBox {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      height: 20%;
      width: 20%;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="gridBox">
      <div id="grid">aaa </div>
    </div>
```

> 2. You haven't given vh or vw to width & height to the div.

```css
 body {
      background-color: teal;
    }

    .gridBox {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      height: 20vh;
      width: 20vw;
      background-color: red;

    }
```

```html
    <div class="gridBox">
      <div id="grid"> </div>
    </div>
```

**Solution:**

Give a width and a height to the div using vh vw or add content to the red box or set the body/html width & height.

Answer (score 1):

gridBox takes height from the body which is null in this case. so try

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Or just give height in pixel for the gridBox.

```
.gridbox {
   height : 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can remove `position: relative;` and it will do the job (for now)

```
  .gridBox {
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add css width/height for body and html

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```